# How many newspapers should buy the man to maximize his expected profit?

Tags: probability

I have a difficult problem :S

A seller buys newspapers to 5 dollars and sells it to 10. A woman is willing to buy all the newspapers that he didn't sell, but only for 2 dollar. If newspapers daily demand is a binomial distribution with n = 20 and p = .5. How many newspapers should
buy the man to maximize his expected profit?

Thanks for your help, have a nice day

Comment: What is the meaning of n here? The daily demand is given in your problem to be 10 newspapers (np). Is that right so far?

Comment: @imranfat:  I presume the daily demand varies between 0 and 20 papers, following the distribution in Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense

Comment: @RossMillikan   Thanks for your help, always help me :D, have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected profit for the $r^{\text{th}}$ paper is $5$ times the chance the demand is at least $r$ minus $3$ times the chance the demand is less than $r$.  this is $$5\sum_{i=r}^{20}{20 \choose i}2^{-20}-3\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}{20 \choose i}2^{-20}$$  You need to find the $r$ where this crosses zero.

Comment: I found a mistake for example if I don't bought anything my expected profits are 0 , but if I substitute 0 in your "formula" my expected profits are 5???

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @user63192:  my formula is the profit on the $r$th paper, not the total profit, so $r=0$ is not allowed.  You can see that for $r=1$ it yields just a little less than $5$ because there will almost always be a demand for the first paper.

Comment: :o :o :o , Sorry , completely true thanks very much again :D